# display image from database in react in laravel

Tags: image, laravel, reactjs

How can i display image form database ? in react ? i am using laravel as backend .this is my table with image
[image]

i am using  {this.props.obj.image} and this is showing the file as shown below 
[image]

as you can see it is showing the file it is not displying image .searched web but it says to import path but all the tutorial are importing statically 
my image location is Assets/Admin/Image .
How can i resolve this

Comment: Did you complete the full path of the image? Put some code to see where is the error coming from.

Comment: i am new to react how can i import image path ?  {this.props.obj.image} showing file from database but i think it is having issue with image path .

public/images/myimage.jpg this is my image location
and i trired this      <img src={this.props.obj.image} alt="hello image" height="200"/> but it showing the image file name from database but path issue

Comment: What is the url you can use to access the image from the browser?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/brand/BrandIndex

Answer (score 1):

When you run a laravel project, you are already in the public folder so you don't have to specify the public folder in the path and "assets" is just a laravel-defined method for accessing the contents of the "public" directory so you shouldn't specify that in the path too.

So you should do something like this:

```
<img src="http://localhost:<your_port>/images/{this.props.obj.image}" alt="hello image" height="200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing just the name of the file in the database, to load the image you need to complete the full path of the image.

If you are storing your files in:

```
{laravel_root_folder}/public/assets/images/
```

Then you should do something like this (btw I know nothing about react but this should kinda work). I'm asuming you are running your server in `localhost` in the `8000` port:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/assets/images/{this.props.obj.image}" alt="hello image" height="200"/>
```

Comment: i am having hard time in react with this line <img src="http://localhost:8000/assets/images/{this.props.obj.image}" alt="hello image" height="200"/>, this way its not working in react.

Comment: As I said I know nothing of React. Now, your problem is that you're not using the full path of the image, there is where the error is generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have directly access to public/storage/images from react (front end side ) for that you have to use following method to generate the URL of image and then just return that url to react side while requesting and use that url in < img src={url} /> to display the picture
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-urls